# Is it possible to integrate win32 api window in c# form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I have a c# form and a window created with win32 api in c++(the code is compiled as static lib, but I can compile it as dll). Is it possible to link and run the code that creates/displays the window from c#?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made all my winapi functions in a dll and called them from c#. With this I can create a window in c++ using winapi that has a c# form as parent window.